# production build of ember app works, but when using ember serve, cookies not sent to api

Tags: rest, cookies, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a rest API running on `localhost:8001/my_app/api/`, and I have apache setup to reverse proxy it from `localhost/my_app/api`. That's working fine.

In order to have permissions to do anything with the api, it requires my session cookie, my `csrftoken` cookie **and** a `X-CSRFToken` HTTP header. I've configured `adapters/application.js` as follows:

## adapters/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DRFAdapter from './drf';

export default DRFAdapter.extend({
   
   headers: Ember.computed(function() {
    return {
      'X-CSRFToken': Ember.get(document.cookie.match(/csrftoken\=([^;]*)/), '1'),
      };
    }).volatile(),

   ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
       hash = hash || {}; // hash may be undefined
       hash.crossDomain = true;
       hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
       return this._super(url, method, hash);
   }
});
```

If I do a `ember build -prod` and copy the contents of the `dist` dir to  `/var/www/myApp/`, apache serves my app, and it works just fine.

It's when I try to use ember-cli's builtin development server where I run into problems.  I'm getting 403 errors from my api.  It turns out that while the `X-CSRFToken` header is being sent *neither* of my cookies are.  If I look in my chrome developer tools, it shows that I have both cookies - they simply aren't in the request headers.  They're both from localhost, so I'm a bit confused.

Also, I currently I have CORS on my rest backend setup. Here are the headers I'm currently receiving:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

I thought that since `allow-credentials == true` and `allow-origin != *` that cookies were supposed to be allowed. sigh.

Here's my API_HOST and contentSecurityPolicy:

## config/environment.js

```
if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = "http://localhost"
    ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
      'default-src': "'none'",
      'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' localhost",
      'font-src': "'self'",
      'connect-src': "'self' localhost",
      'img-src': "'self'",
      'style-src': "'self'",
      'media-src': "'self'"
   };
 }
```

As you can see above, the api requests are being sent through my reverse proxy.  I've played around with `ember serve --proxy` trying both `http://localhost:80/` and `http://localhost:8001/` but neither have helped. I've also tried setting my development `ENV.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8001/';` with and without the various proxy values.

This edit, build, deploy, refresh my browser, test, & repeat process is **REALLY** slow and getting old **REALLY** fast.

Could someone please explain to me how to get the ember-cli development server to properly access my rest api?

Comment: localhost:80 and localhost:8001 are different hosts as far as the cookie same-origin policy is concerned.

Comment: @elithrar Thanks for the response.  I did an edit and added the "development" snippet from my `environment.js`.  Does my content security policy look sane for my development server which is running on localhost;4200, and is reverse proxying my localhost:8001 backend via localhost:80?

Comment: The CSP headers in a dev environment only trigger warnings, so they don't matter too much. But CSP won't impact cookies - they're unrelated.

Comment: @elithrar yeah, the way I have it configured, i don't even get the warnings anymore.  if it's not the CSP, and I have CORS setup properly (hopefully), any idea why my 'localhost' cookies aren't being sent from my ember serve (localhost:4200) site?